# Trying to show products from database

Tags: php

I am creating a estore for my website and I'm starting out by just trying to display the product information from my database in a html table but I can't get it to display.   It shows the table but no information in it.  Here's what I have:

```
<?php
    require 'connectto.php';

 //get all product data
      $query = 'SELECT * FROM Products';
      $products = $db->query($query);
      $products = $products->fetch();
?>





<table width="500" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th >Description</th>
<th >Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>

</tr>
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $product['Name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product['Description']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product['Price']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product['Quantity']; ?></td>
<td><input type = "submit" value = "Delete" align = "right" ></td>

</tr> 
<?php } ?>

</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's data in there? Does that query run manually produce results? Are you getting any errors that you might be ignoring?

Comment: What's here  `print_r($products);` ?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the information I have stored in my database to display on the html page

Answer (score 0):

Replace `fetch ( )` with  `fetch_all ( )` .

The error was in `fetch  ()`, because it return one row from product table.

Answer (score 0):

Change here: `$products = $products->fetch();`

To:
`$products = $products->fetch_all();`

or

`$products = $products->fetch_object();`